# Custom attribute not showing on all products config pages in the admin area

Tags: php, magento

I created a custom attribute in the admin area. When I go to a product to manage and to change the value of the attribute, the attribute label and input is not showing.

I tried everything but nothing helped me.

What can be the issue?

Thanks in advance, waiting for your answer please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afer creating the attribute **you have to assign that attribute to the attribute set**. Then only you can see the attribute field in product edit/create form.

Refer this [**Link**](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html)